# Does Win7 load commonly-used programs into memory?

Tags: 7-zip

I have this system for my files where I have a whole hierarchy of folders containing only zip files, and an identical hierarchy of folders where those zip files are extracted to, like a source and target system. The hierarchies in question (the folders by themselves) are extracted from zip files to their relevant locations, so as to preserve dates/times and attributes, as it is easier than using endless MKDIR and ATTRIB commands in batch files.

However, to maintain those attributes and dates/times, every subfolder that is extracted calls for FOUR calls to 7-Zip. I'm concerned about whether or not this will result in wear and tear on my hard disk (to frequently delete entire folders and unzip them again) and if Win7 has to load 7-Zip each and every single time. I would imagine this would severely shorten the life of an SSD, too.

So, should I find a way to reduce calls to 7-Zip, or even to not delete the target folders at all?

Comment: yes, windows does cache common programs, unless you ram is full, but at the same time, the wear to your disk won't come as the result of reading a few times for 7zip.exe, or even deleting directories. it will come from creating/deleting files. directories exist only as metadata, and a hard disk will deal with billions of reads in its expected lifespan.

Comment: Several questions @Foebane.  Why are you doing this?  Is this a daily process of recreating the ZIPs, or live?  How often do the files change?  Are you writing the ZIPs to a second disk, and if not, why not?  Are many files being rewritten simultaneously, in which case, can the ZIP file rewrites be queued?  Might a database be better for this data set?

Comment: The files are basically retro computer emulators and their associated demos and games, but every time I add new files via updates, I have to reinstall everything in the source hierarchy, and then extract the contents of all the zips to the target hierarchy. Same for the Software (demos/games) side of things, and same for the Emulators (when I want to reset them to defaults).